# $\nabla p=-\rho \nabla E \implies p=-\rho E +\mathrm{constant}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

I'm not sure about the following mathematical passage.

Consider the general equation of Hydrostatic in the case of **conservative forces** acting
$$\nabla p=-\rho \nabla E \tag{1}$$
Where $p$ is pressure, $\rho$ is density and $E$ is the potential energy per unit of mass.

Does it follows from $(1)$ necessarily that

$$p=-\rho E +\mathrm{constant}\tag{2}$$

?

I mean $(2)$ clearly satisfies $(1)$ but is that the only possible solution for $(1)$?

Comment: If the density is constant, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Consider rearranging the equation as 
$$
\nabla (p+\rho E) = 0
$$

This implies that all the partial derivatives of $(p+\rho E)$ vanish at every point, and thus $(p+\rho E)$ is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

You can work backwards. Start with $p~=~-\rho E~+~C$ and take the gradient and you get
$$
\nabla p~=~-(\nabla\rho)E~-~\rho\nabla E.
$$
For a uniform density the $\nabla\rho~=~0$ and you get your initial expression.